# scp copies folder but not contents of the folder

Tags: ubuntu, windows, scp, file-transfer

I have been trying to get this to work for a few days now, but I can't figure it out. I am trying to `scp` a folder full of `.tar` files from my Ubuntu-Server Server to my Windows Desktop. I want to push it from my server to my Desktop, because I'd like to automate the process via a `bash` script.

I am using a command like this:

```
scp -r path/to/folder Username@Windowsmachineip:C:/path/to/folder/
```

When I execute the command, I get the error `no such file or directory`, but it does create a folder with the name of the folder on my server.

What I **can** do is a copy single files, but only if I specify a name for the file on my desktop, like this

```
scp -r path/to/folder/file Username@Windowsmachineip:C:/path/to/folder/file
```

If I try it without the filename at the end, I get the same error. I also tried it with the `-p` flag, following a suggestion, but that throws the same error. I tried pulling from the Server to my desktop, but get the same error. I also tried sftp which gives this output:

```
dest open "/E:/backup/minecraft/backup_minecraft_24_03_2024_06:01:04.tar": No such file or directory
upload "backup/minecraft/backup_minecraft_24_03_2024_06:01:04.tar" to "/E:/backup/minecraft/backup_minecraft_24_03_2024_06:01:04.tar" failed
```

The error I get with scp and -v flag is:

```
scp: debug1: fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Sending file modes: C0666 471111680 backup_minecraft_23_03_2024_22:29:33.tar
Sink: C0666 471111680 backup_minecraft_23_03_2024_22:29:33.tar
scp: E:/backup/minecraft/backup_minecraft_23_03_2024_22:29:33.tar: No such file or directory
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: As `scp` needs to use the remote shell to run `scp` on the remote side, this is fragile. See "History, SCP and SFTP" [here](https://superuser.com/a/1733992/432690). In your case the remote side is Windows, pathnames and quoting rules there are somewhat different, but it's the responsibility of your client `scp` to pass them to the remote side. Your client `scp` knows nothing about Windows. I may be wrong but it's not uncommon to see weird errors when worlds collide (Linux vs Windows). What is the remote shell? Can you try SFTP? Or does your `scp` support SFTP? (see the already linked answer).

Comment: Works for me from a Pi to Windows 11. Do your source or destination paths contain spaces? If so, please provide the exact command and paths in your question

Comment: Can you just use a wildcard? Something like `scp path/to/folder/* Username@Windowsmachineip:C:/path/to/folder/`.

Comment: So first of all thanks for the comments.
@KamilMaciorowski so I log into my Ubuntu Server through Powershell 7, but i also tried Command Prompt, and Powershell. Oh Sorry I forgot, I already tried sftp, i get the same error. I'm adding the verbose output of scp and the error from sftp to my original post

Comment: @ChrisDavies My Folders and Files dont contain any spaces, they are: /home/backup/minecraft and E:/backup/minecraft

Comment: @Robbie I just tried that, unfortunately i get the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have colons in your filenames: `backup_minecraft_23_03_2024_22:29:33.tar`

These are [not permitted characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) for Windows systems. Remove (or replace) the colons and the files will transfer correctly

> The following [are] reserved characters:
>
> - `<` (less than)
> - `>` (greater than)
> - `:` (colon)
> - `"` (double quote)
> - `/` (forward slash)
> - `\` (backslash)
> - `|` (vertical bar or pipe)
> - `?` (question mark)
> - `*` (asterisk)